# Tabs and tab content not displaying content on click

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I've created some clickable tabs but for some reason the tab content does not display on click. I can't see anything out of place with my code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<div className="container-tabs">
    <ul className="tablist">
        <li data-tab-target="engage" className="active-tab tab">01</li>
        <li data-tab-target="scope" className="tab">02</li>
        <li data-tab-target="build" className="tab">03</li>
    </ul>
    <div className="tab-content py">
        <div id="engage" data-tab-content className="active-tab">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus aperiam repudiandae animi rerum
                quae porro molestias placeat iure nostrum doloribus.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="scope" data-tab-content>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam sit iste, veritatis iusto nulla delectus
                voluptatibus neque. Tenetur, aperiam itaque.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="build" data-tab-content>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut quas nulla, necessitatibus expedita illum
                in numquam omnis tempora illo consequuntur.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]');
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]');

tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
        tabContents.forEach(tabContents => {
            tabContents.classList.remove('active-tab')
        })
        tabs.forEach(tab => {
            tab.classList.remove('active-tab')
        })
        tab.classList.add('active-tab')
        target.classList.add('active-tab')
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS for that HTML?

Comment: Try looking at the browser console when you click a tab. For one, there's no `tab.dataset.tabTarget`, therefore `target` is `undefined`. Next, the values in there don't have a `#` at the start which you will need for an id selector to pass to `querySelector`

Comment: Change `document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)` to `document.querySelector(\`#${tab.dataset.tabTarget}\`)`

Comment: Thanks guys but that doesn't work. I'll post the CSS up later I'm away from my PC at the moment. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I managed to get it working, the tabs appear elsewhere on the website, something I wasn't aware of until a colleague mentioned it! It's working now, we had to re work the JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a variable with the selected tab, and go from there, also it's better to have only one listener on your tablist, i would set an id to `<ul class="tablist">` for faster select.. something like this:

```js
const tabs = document.getElementById("tablist");
let selected = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tab-target]")[0];
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tab-content]");
let selectedContent = tabContents[0];
tabs.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  selected.classList.remove("active-tab");
  selected = e.target;
  selected.classList.toggle("active-tab");
  const index = [...selected.parentNode.children].indexOf(selected);
  selectedContent.classList.remove("active-tab");
  selectedContent = tabContents[index];
  selectedContent.classList.toggle("active-tab");
});
```

```css
.active-tab {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-tabs">
  <ul class="tablist" id="tablist">
    <li data-tab-target="engage" class="active-tab tab">01</li>
    <li data-tab-target="scope" class="tab">02</li>
    <li data-tab-target="build" class="tab">03</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content py">
    <div id="engage" data-tab-content class="active-tab">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus aperiam repudiandae animi rerum quae porro molestias placeat iure nostrum doloribus.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="scope" data-tab-content>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam sit iste, veritatis iusto nulla delectus voluptatibus neque. Tenetur, aperiam itaque.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="build" data-tab-content>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut quas nulla, necessitatibus expedita illum in numquam omnis tempora illo consequuntur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```